# String length using pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers

I was looking up some code tricks.  I found one that I get the basics but I don't understand why it exits.  It has to do with a string pointer in a while loop.  Usually I don't deal with strings as I work primarily on embedded systems...gadgets.   I need to understand why the string pointer comes to an end when it is not being incremented.

so in this code here you pass in a pointer to a string and then in this while loop you increment the counter witch is added to the pointer so the address accessed keeps getting incremented. I get all that.  My question is why does it finish?  what happens such that the while loop evaluates to false and exits?  to me it would seem to just keep on increment to the size of an int then wrap around again.

```
int string_length(char *s)
{
   int c = 0;

   while(*(s+c))
      c++;

   return c;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `strlen()` from the standard string lib?

Comment: A "string" is a series of non-null characters followed by a character whose value is `0`

Comment: Besides it is very simple, try to go through the code and see what it's doing.

Comment: Also note that `*(s+c)` is just another way of writing `s[c]`, if that's easier to understand.

Comment: @ MightyPork...The intent of this was to do it without using the lib func.  I was asked by a recruiter about this.  I gave them a slightly different answer using recursive function that looks for the null character.  I didn't Dawn on me that the While would evaluate a string null character the same way.  I do not use strings in any products I have been working on for years.

Comment: @ MightyPork... also the question isn't how to count a string length.  the question was... I looked up some code on the web and didn't understand it.  I wanted someone to clarify why the while loop evaluates the string termination char the same way as a logical false result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`while(*(s+c))` returns false when the null character is encountered and breaks the loop

Answer (score 2):

A string is an arrary of chars, of which the very last one is the terminating character - \0. The evaluation of while checks every char starting at position indcitated by pointer s, then shifting it to the next char (next array entry) by adding c to the start address. Once \0 - the terminating character - is reached the loop breaks.

Answer (score 0):

```
int lungh(char *p){
    char *r = p;
    while(*p++!='\0'){}
    return p-r;
}
```